# applyTransformation method not invoked in custom animation

Tags: android

The applyTransformation method in my custom Animation is somethimes not being called after I started my animation with view.startAnimation(myAnimation). Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 7):

Try this.. worked well for me.

```
 view.startAnimation(myAnimation);
 View parent = (View)view.getParent();
 parent.invalidate();
```